# Is $site_name , $logo ,$site_slogan are part of render array $page?

Tags: theming

is $site_name , $logo  ,$site_slogan variables values are store in render array $page? or they are independent from $page? if they are independent.then list of variables that have same nature?

Answer (score 1):

The variables you use in templates aren't really part of the render arrays themselves.  They are created by the various preprocess and process functions and added to the `$variables` array.  By default, those you list are added in either a [`template_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) or [`template_preprocess_html()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7), which your theme can have, too.  Look at the source to see what is going on.  For example, the stock `template_preprocess_page` sets `$site_slogan` like

```
$variables['site_slogan'] = (theme_get_setting('toggle_slogan') ?
                            filter_xss_admin(variable_get('site_slogan', '')) : '');
```

To aid in figuring this out, I suggest installing the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, and looking at the [functions](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21devel%21devel.module/7) that it provides.  For example, you can do

```
dpr($variables);
```

to get a dump of everything in the `$variables` array, or you can do

```
kpr($page);
```

to poke through the `$page` object via [Krumo](http://krumo.kaloyan.info/), which is included in Devel.

Comment: sir,any debugging tool that tell this variable is part of renderable array $page and this one not?